# pybind11: using setuptools to link

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm trying to use Python's `setuptools` to build a variant of this [example](https://github.com/pybind/python_example). In the example, there is only one file, `main.cpp`. However, in my version, I'm adding in another class. Therefore, there are a total of three files:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include "myClass.h"

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(python_example, m) {
    m.doc() = R"pbdoc(
        Pybind11 example plugin

    )pbdoc";

    py::class_<myClass>(m, "myClass")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def("addOne", &myClass::addOne)
    .def("getNumber", &myClass::getNumber)
    ;
}
```

**myClass.h**

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

class myClass
{
public:
    int number;

    myClass();
    void addOne();

    int getNumber();
};
```

**myClass.cpp**

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include "myClass.h"

myClass::myClass() {
    number = 1;
}
void myClass::addOne() {
    number = number + 1;
}

int myClass::getNumber() {
    return number;
}
```

If I use the original `setup.py` file in the example, it does not work, since I need to link `myClass.cpp` with `main.cpp`. How can I do that using `setuptools`? Basically I am looking for the `setuptools` equivalent of CMake's `target_link_libraries`.

I'm asking this because my experience in CMake is minimal. Using `setuptools` would be easier for me.

Comment: I believe the `ext_modules` parameter to `setuptools.setup` might be what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that what you are looking from is `setuptools.Extension`. I highly advice you to check out this great example: https://github.com/pybind/python_example. It should be able to guide you in what you need to do.

Here is what I extracted for your code. Note that it is basically copy-paste from the [example](https://github.com/pybind/python_example).

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext

import sys, re
import setuptools
import pybind11


# (c) Sylvain Corlay, https://github.com/pybind/python_example
def has_flag(compiler, flagname):

  import tempfile

  with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', suffix='.cpp') as f:

    f.write('int main (int argc, char **argv) { return 0; }')

    try:
      compiler.compile([f.name], extra_postargs=[flagname])
    except setuptools.distutils.errors.CompileError:
      return False

  return True


# (c) Sylvain Corlay, https://github.com/pybind/python_example
def cpp_flag(compiler):

  if   has_flag(compiler,'-std=c++14'): return '-std=c++14'
  elif has_flag(compiler,'-std=c++11'): return '-std=c++11'
  raise RuntimeError('Unsupported compiler: at least C++11 support is needed')


# (c) Sylvain Corlay, https://github.com/pybind/python_example
class BuildExt(build_ext):

  c_opts = {
    'msvc': ['/EHsc'],
    'unix': [],
  }

  if sys.platform == 'darwin':
    c_opts['unix'] += ['-stdlib=libc++', '-mmacosx-version-min=10.7']

  def build_extensions(self):
    ct = self.compiler.compiler_type
    opts = self.c_opts.get(ct, [])
    if ct == 'unix':
      opts.append('-DVERSION_INFO="%s"' % self.distribution.get_version())
      opts.append(cpp_flag(self.compiler))
    elif ct == 'msvc':
      opts.append('/DVERSION_INFO=\\"%s\\"' % self.distribution.get_version())
    for ext in self.extensions:
      ext.extra_compile_args = opts
    build_ext.build_extensions(self)


ext_modules = [
  Extension(
    'python_example',
    ['main.cpp', 'myClass.cpp'],
    include_dirs=[
      pybind11.get_include(False),
      pybind11.get_include(True ),
    ],
    language='c++'
  ),
]


setup(
  name             = 'python_example',
  ext_modules      = ext_modules,
  install_requires = ['pybind11>=2.2.0'],
  cmdclass         = {'build_ext': BuildExt},
  zip_safe         = False,
)
```

Note that a large portion of the code does not deal with your specific question but rather with getting C++11/14 to work in a robust way. I tried to leave it mostly as it was in the original example, also to get a complete working code here.

Comment: Great answer. How does `setuptools` know that I'm linking `myClass.cpp` to `main.cpp`, not the other around (i.e. linking `main.cpp` to `myClass.cpp`)?

Comment: @tryingtosolve . I don't think that there exists any 'directionality' in linking. That what matters is that everything is linked together at runtime. You can thus separately compile each source file to an object file, and only as a final step link everything together. The compiler will know how to deal with dependencies when compiling the individual source files because of the headers.

Comment: You can easily try this by changing your `main.cpp` to contain an `int main(){ ...; return 0; }` and use `g++ -c main.cpp; g++ -c myClass.cpp` to get two object files (these are really independent steps). and only them link them together by `g++ myClass.o main.o` (order does not matter).